# Where does bash store environment variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to permanently delete two env variables used in my WSL instance (using bash as my shell). Right now I have to `unset` these variables every time I want to disable them. I know all I have to do is delete the corresponding lines of the configuration file containing these variables, but `~.bash_rc` has no environment variables and `/etc/environment` has only one variable (I can see far more when I type the `env` command). I also don't have a `~.bash_profile` as far as I can tell. I'm at my wits end trying to figure out where these bash variables might be residing. Any thoughts of where I should look?

Comment: It might be simpler to just add the specific `unset` commands at the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile`. It depends on how *complete* a solution you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `PS4` variable and `grep` but keep in mind that an update might revert whatever you have edited/removed.

```sh
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE:' bash -xilc '' 2>&1 | grep MY_ENV_VARIABLE
```

You can have a look at the manual about the meaning of `-x -i -l -c` options.